# POP3 receive email encoding C#

Tags: c#, email, encoding, pop3

I use **POP3** to receive email. But encoding error like, email's Subject "主题" turns to "涓婚". Chinese errors, strong text when the content of the text's language is English, no errors. Who can tell me, what should I do for it? The code below:

```
POP3 pop = new POP3();
pop.Connect("userName", "password", "pop.126.com", 110);//smtp.126.com
pop.DownloadMessages();
for (int i = 1; i < pop.Messages.Count; i++)
{
    Email email = new Email();
    Message msg = pop.Messages[i];
    email.From = msg.From;
    email.FromName = msg.FromName;
    email.Body = msg.HTMLBody;
    email.Title = msg.Subject;
}
```

Comment: Please improve the quality of your question.  We need more information and please show the research you have already done. thanks

Comment: As far as I remember, there is no direct support for POP3 in C#. Where does this `POP3` class come from?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure what POP3 library you are using, but it is clearly broken and there's nothing you can do to "fix" your code to make it work beyond switching to another POP3 library, such as my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library which is the only library that correctly handles charsets in all cases (most will handle Latin1 ok, but completely fail for CJK charsets).

The reason that most clients break for anything outside of Latin1 (ISO-8859-1) is that most email libraries have parsers that only work on strings. In order to convert the message data from bytes into a string, they need to pick a `System.Text.Encoding` (and most pick ISO-8859-1). They assume that email messages follow the rules outlined in the various RFCs that restrict email headers to US-ASCII, but it is *very* common for clients to ignore these rules.

Unlike those other parsers, MailKit's email parser parses byte streams and so does not require charset conversion before it can start parsing a message. This allows the parser to properly handle mixed charsets in the headers and body.

Comment: Thing is, I'd expect a guy who writes a free MIT licences library to be exactly the guy to be monitoring these types of question and probably be the best to answer them. They are exactly the types of guys who know about this stuff. So...why smash him down. Rules be damned. If he's not being helpful release the dogs. Use some judgement though eh?

Comment: Why my comment has been deleted?